# Bitbucket merge branches confusion

Tags: android, git, github, merge, bitbucket

I am new in using git, and I have a confusion about how to merge properly branches. I am using Android Studio integrated VCS, and each time I need to create new future I was adding a new branch. Like you can see in this pic:

[image]

I have following branches:

1. Master
2. download_web_content
3. maintenance but never merge them.

So my confusion is how to merge last two into the master one and why my project doesn't look like:
[image]

I was following official [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-unmerged-branches-389778602.html?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fconfluence.atlassian.com%2Fbitbucket%2Fmanage-unmerged-branches-389778602.html&application=cac) but did't get it...

p.s. Please don't mention SourceTree tool. I'd like to use Android Studio or Git Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio helps you to do merges inside the IDE.

Just follow these steps:

- check out the branch that should have "all" features (in your case that should be "master")
- click on the branches list and select your feature branch (e.g. download_web_content), click on it and select "merge"

Android Studio merges the changes for you and prompts conflicts if there are any.

[Here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/) is a small Tutorial that could also help :)

Hope this helps :)